# Abnormal burst in the First Posts review queue?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, review

From the review queue of StackOverflow:

[image]

As you can see. Just few minutes ago, there was a sudden burst in the First Posts review queue. Most posts in the queue were posted around 20~30 days ago.

Does anyone know the cause of this sudden burst in the number?

Comment: The clean-up script just ran about an hour ago, causing a bunch of questions to be deleted, and other questions to become users' "first posts" in their place.